# How to update a single property in a React state (function component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, destructuring

I want to update a state with a couple of values from a form with a single change handler in a function component. I cannot figure out how to set a single property in the state in a proper way. I have seen this works in a class component.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

export function Example(){
  const [user, setUser] = useState({nickname: '', age: 0})

  const handleChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target
    setUser({ [name]: value })
  }

  return(
     <form>
       <input name="nickname" onChange={handleChange} />
       <input name="age" onChange={handleChange} />
       <button onClick={(e) => {
         e.preventDefault()
         console.log(user)
        }}>Show User</button>
     </form>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Example />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

The code above does not work the way I want to since it always overrides the whole state and not only the corresponding property.

I receive:

```
Object {age: "24"}
Object {nickname: "Lala"}
```

I want:

```
Object {age: "24", nickname: "Lala"}
```

What is the best practice to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to do it this way:

```
const handleChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target
    setUser({ ...user, [name]: value })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! That was easier than I thought xD

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are very close to the solution in the following line

```
  setUser({ [name]: value })
```

But you need to ensure the persistency of the legacy values that this input doesn't touch, therefore you need to change it to

```
  setUser({ ...user, [name]: value })
```

Answer (score 0):

const [state,setSate]={data1:"d1",data2:"d2",.....}

now we can call the statement in appropriate callback function(consider to update data1 & data2):

```
onChange={(e)=>{
    setState((state)=>{return ({...state, data1: e.target.value,data2: e.target.value, }) })
}}
```